# Word2Vec: Error received at uploading a pre-trained word2vec file using Gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, fasttext

> I receive an error when trying to upload a pre-trained word2vec file
>   (compiled with fasttext) using Gensim. File has '.vec' extension and
>   can be found here:
>   http://89.38.230.23/word_embeddings/we/corola.300.20.vec.zip
>
> What I've tried so far: Option 1: KeyedVectors from gensim.models
>   Option 2: FastText wrapper

```
#Option 1
    from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
    model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('Word_embeddings/corola.300.20.vec', binary=True)
######

#Option 2
    from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText
    model = FastText.load_word2vec_format('Word_embeddings/corola.300.20.vec')
```

> Error option 1: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte
>   0x9b in position 0: invalid start byte
>
> Deprecation Error option 2: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use
>   gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.
>
> I need the correct method to successfully upload the word2vec file,
>   using gensim.
>
> Thank you.

Comment: Which class was used to train the `corola.300.20.vec.zip` file, and how was it saved? What happens when you use that same class to load the file? (Also: a `DeprecationWarning` **isn't** a fatal error. If that's truly all you see when you try your 2nd method, you may still have a working loaded `model`.)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it's just fine to use the `unicode_errors='ignore'` parameter, since there can be errors in the word embedding file. Just try:

```py
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('Word_embeddings/corola.300.20.vec', binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore')
```